# Summability of the following sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Let $\{a_k\}$ be a *non-increasing* sequence tending to zero. Suppose that $\sum_{k} a_k^\theta < \infty$ for some $\theta < 2$. Show that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty (\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^{-2} )^{-1/2} < \infty$.

The text I am reading claims that this is trivial and omit the proof. But, obviously I am too laggard to see the trick. Can anyone give some hint? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using that $(a_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N}}$ is decreasing, we get that
$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^{-2} \geq \sum_{k=\lfloor n/2 \rfloor}^n a_k^{-2}  \geq  \frac{n}{2} (a_{\lfloor n/2 \rfloor})^{-2}.$$
Thus
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \Big( \sum_{k=1}^n a_k^{-2} \Big)^{-1/2} \ll \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-1/2} a_n.$$
Now, apply the Hölder-inequality with $p=\theta$ and $q= \theta/(\theta-1)>2$. Note that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-q/2}$ is convergent, because $q>2$.

Edit: One case is missing. Here, I have supposed that $\theta >1$, otherwise we can just use $n^{-1/2} a_n \leq a_n^\theta$.

Comment: But when $\{a_k\}$ is decreasing, $\{a_k^{-2}\}$ is increasing, so I don't think the first inequality is true..

Comment: Perhaps we can modify the first inequality to be $\sum_{k=1}^n a_k^{-2} \geq [\frac{n}{2}] a_{[\frac{n}{2}]}^{-2}$ where $[x]$ denotes the integer part of $x$. Then your reasoning seems to apply. Anyway, thanks for the answer!

Comment: Yes, you are right! I have corrected my mistake: Your second comment works fine.